# Trying to display an image and label when making a selection from the UIPicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uipickerview

I have an array for the geek names and an array for the careers of each geek. The geek names should appear in the UIPicker. When a name is selected, the image and the career of the selected player should be displayed at the bottom of the picker. I am unable to place the images in an array as _ImageView = @[@".... because every time I attempt it my screen goes black. When I delete it, it runs but then it crashes right after it opens on my device and I get the following message:

```
2013-05-02 13:40:03.761 Assignment5[2968:c07] -[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7549d30
2013-05-02 13:40:03.780 Assignment5[2968:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7549d30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1d1d4bd 0x1c81bbc 0x1c8194e 0xc634 0xd25f 0x642dd 0x10e36b0 0x228efc0 0x228333c 0x228eeaf 0x1032bd 0x4bb56 0x4a66f 0x4a589 0x497e4 0x4961e 0x4a3d9 0x4d2d2 0xf799c 0x44574 0x4476f 0x44905 0x4d917 0x1196c 0x1294b 0x23cb5 0x24beb 0x16698 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1217a 0x13ffc 0x1e9d 0x1dc5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Here is my code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Assignment5ViewController : UIViewController
<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *career;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *geekImageView;

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *geekNames;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *careerNames;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface Assignment5ViewController ()

@end

@implementation Assignment5ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _geekNames = @[@"Alan Turing", @"Bill Gates", @"Dennis Ritchie", @"James Gosling", @"Larry Wall", @"Linus Torvalds", @"Mark Zuckerberg", @"Steve Jobs", @"Tim Berners-Lee", @"Vinton Cerf"];

    _careerNames = @[@"Conceived Turing Machine", @"Started Microsoft", @"Created C and Unix", @"Created Java Language", @"Created Perl Language", @"Created Linux OS", @"Created Facebook", @"Started Apple", @"Created World-Wide-Web", @"Created TCP/IP"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark PickerView DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberofComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _geekNames.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_geekNames objectAtIndex:row];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView Delegate

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    _careerNames = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", [_geekNames objectAtIndex:row]];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from that error, that you've set the picker's data source to a UIView rather than your view controller. How did you set the data source? Did you do that in IB? You should delete that connection and redo it.

Comment: How do I do that? I am sorry but I have never done this before and I am super confused. I've never coded in objective c so I am trying to understand it.

Comment: @user1787078, how do you do what? Delete the connection and redo it? Did you make the connection in the first place? How did you do that?

Comment: Yes I did but I followed a book. Still trying to grasp it all.

Comment: @user1787078, If you right click (or control click) on the picker view in IB, it will bring up a black window that will show all the connections. What does it say to the right of "dataSource"?

Comment: Yes and I selected both the datasource and the delegate. As soon as I did that and ran it, I got a black box. Ok, I think I know now what you are saying. I will give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: ok I did that. And as soon as I made the connection I got the same error.

Comment: @user1787078. Put this log as the first line in viewDidLoad, and see what it gives you: NSLog(@"%@",self.picker.dataSource)